# BitTorrent Sync - Exclude All except

Tags: sync, bittorrent, dotfiles, bittorrent-sync

I'd like to exclude all content except some specific folders and files...

for example

```
*
!somefolder  #except this folder
```

how can I do this with .SyncIgnore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to include files on whitelist - unfortunately, this is not supported at current stage of Sync development. There is no "except these" tag in .SyncIgnore list.

RomanZ

Comment: IMHO this is very necessary functionality, also UI way to select ignored files is needed for the application if they are not making product only for geeks but for average users too... Cant understand why they couldnt do like gitignore does